# C# Dynamics AX implementation contactinfoview fields always null

Tags: c#, soap, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm currently trying to integrate Dynamics AX (2012) data into my ASP.NET MVC project by calling the SOAP webservices that AX exposes.

When calling the ContactPersonService I get all the fields from each `ContactPerson` and the `Person` entity which works fine. However, when I access the `ContactInfoView` (and `PostalAddressView` for the matter) entities, all of it's fields are null (and bool fields are `False`) even though I have set the contact information on the person in AX.

What is strange is that if I use soapUI to make the *exact same* call to the service, I get all the fields with data as it should.

There are no exceptions thrown in my MVC project that I'm aware of.

Does anyone know why these entities are not filled in with data? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey - are you sure the soapUI is making the EXACT same call - have you captured the soap packet? I would be willing to bet something is different...

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks a lot for your input :-) Sorry I didn't update this question - I forgot about it, to be honest. The (AX) server admins simply restarted the server and then everything was fine ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple AX server restart solved the problem right away :-)

Comment: I want to implement the same functionality but in windows application. Can you give me solution. I have also asked question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31537272/2393573)