# CRUD operation in AX tables using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, axapta

I am new in AX.

My boss gave me to task to access tables of AX 2012 from C#.

Following are the criteria:

1. Code should be generic. (user will give me table name, column name
   and any condition if there, to execute insert, delete, update or
   select queries).
2. Client and server may be or may not be in same
3. Client and server may be or may not be in same
   domain Without any installation on client machine

I tried Business connector. But, we can't use business connector outside the domain and it requires installation on client machine

I tried web service. But, We need to add service reference for each web service group.

Is there any thing best suitable for my requirement? Or am I missing something while using above two ways?

Please help to resolve this issue. I am doing this since last month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AifGenericDocumentService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aifgenericdocumentservice.aspx). The wsdl is available by default at `http://_AOS_:_8101_/DynamicsAx/Services/AifGDS?singleWsdl`.

This is a generic web service, so if you don't know the schema for target tables you can also use [`MetadataService`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg880762.aspx) at `http://_AOS_:_8101_/DynamicsAx/Services/MetadataService?singleWsdl`

You can see an example at https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/microsoftdynamicsaxintegration/archive/2012/05/06/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-application-integration-framework-custom-web-service-loosely-typed

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matej, I have succeeded in "CREATE" operation. I want to perform all the CRUD operations. Can you help me in that?

Comment: Read operation can be done by `read` or `find` method. The [`update`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aifgenericdocumentservice.update.aspx) accepts same XML as `create`. All this methods (including [`delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aifgenericdocumentservice.delete.aspx)) requires `query`, like in X++ where you have to specify `forUpdate` before UD operations.

Comment: I got read operation [here](http://ax2012aifintegration.blogspot.in/2012_05_01_archive.html).
Is it good to use?